# super simple FTP server for Linux

Tags: ftp

So I am having trouble with shared folders in virt-manager and would like to get around this by using FTP instead, but I am somewhat lost in configuring vsftpd - and it sounds like overkill for the task anyway.

All I want is:

- Share a single directory, read/write
- Have one fixed username/password combination, ideally *not* tied to an actual user on the host
- Listen on one address only (the virtual network adapter)

And I *don't* want to get lost in configuration of a powerful server intended for so much more.

I don't even need this to be a service. I can start it manually when I need the share. But I can use a service if it's there.

The host system is Fedora 29 at present.

Could someone please advise which FTP server I want to use?

Comment: Why not use `scp` or `sftp`, which are built on `ssh`? Assuming you're already running `ssh` no new service (or configuration) is required

Comment: Consider using tftp!

Comment: with `scp` you cannot secure copy folders, instead use `tar` to tar up a folder and all its subfolders and subfiles into something like *folder.tar* then do a single `scp folder.tar user@host:/validfolder/`.

Comment: then on the destination system where it was sent, it's a simple `tar -xf folder.tar` to untar it back to what it was.

Comment: @ron - `scp -r` works just fine for copying entire folders.